# numpy- Make an array of 2's

Tags: python, numpy

I know there are functions for making arrays of zeros and ones, but I need to make an array of twos.

My ones array works:

```py
np.ones((20), dtype=int).reshape(4, 5)
```

I just want to replace all the ones with twos in a short line of code.

Comment: just multiply by 2.  It only adds 2 characters to your line of code.  Or add 2 to an `np.zeros`

Answer (score 0):

Try [`np.full()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full) where you specify `fill_value=2`:

```py
arr = np.full(20, 2, dtype=int).reshape(4, 5)
print(arr)
```

Prints:

```
[[2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2 2]]
```

Comment: Please, try looking for potential duplicates before you fire off an answer 3 minutes after the question was submitted. Is this really so novel that it warrants another answer added to the pile? Even the OP figured it out in 12 minutes.

Comment: @DanMašek, maybe he was writing this at the same time.  The question is trivial enough to get multiple answers.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind! I found it np.full((10), 2, dtype=float).reshape(2, 5)